# Tax Basis and Bargain Element for Incentive Stock Option on Foreign Stock Exchange

Tags: united-states, foreign-exchange, capital-gains-tax, employee-stock-options, alternative-minimum-tax

The US company I work for recently went public, however the powers that be chose to do the IPO on the Australian Stock Exchange (ASX). I am based in the United States.

My stock option strike price is quoted in USD, but the stock is quoted on ASX as AUD.

These are Incentive Stock Options that I intend to exercise for long term holding, so this is initially for AMT calculation in USA.

When I file my AMT, and down the road for capital gains taxes, what exchange rate and on what date to I use to calculate the basis and capital gains as well as the bargain element for AMT.